# Unable to Publish to WAS 7.0 on RAD 7.5

Tags: websphere, publish, rad

It was working fine until my PC got restarted due to power outage and now the publishing gives the following error.. Please help me solve this

> The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start. View the Details to display the exceptions and server logs that occurred during the publish.
>
> ======== SPMEAR ========
>
> Application Failed to Install. SPMEAR
>     Application Failed to Install. SPMEAR
>     Please see server logs for more details.
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.model.CompositionUnitConfig.readJ2EEAppDeployment(CompositionUnitConfig.java:291)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.model.CompositionUnitConfig.read(CompositionUnitConfig.java:225)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.model.CompositionUnitFactoryImpl.readCompositionUnitFromCompositionUnitSpec(CompositionUnitFactoryImpl.java:76)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateBLATask._validateBLAUninstall(ValidateBLATask.java:548)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateBLATask._performTaskAsSystem(ValidateBLATask.java:122)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateBLATask$1.run(ValidateBLATask.java:91)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4189)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSpecified(ContextManagerImpl.java:4347)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateBLATask.performTask(ValidateBLATask.java:88)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:284)
>     [8/2/13 23:17:58:057 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)

This is the stack trace

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.ibm.etools.wrd.websphere.v7.internal.operations.ApplicationUpdateOperation.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.etools.wrd.websphere.v7.internal.operations.WASPublisherImpl.publishDelta(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v7.core.internal.WASServerBehaviour.publishWrdDelta(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v7.core.internal.WASServerBehaviour.publishModules(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

maybe a corrupted files inside your tmp ... try to clean you /tmp and restart if not solved .. try to change your context root as a temp solution

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this :

Go to Window -> Preference->Server->websphere Application Server.
enable Allow applications containing errors to be published on a server option.

BR,
Priya